# Will there be any effect on my joomla website after port change?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have my Joomla website up and running, it's running on php port 80, now I want to change that port.

So I want to know whether it will affect in any way my existing Joomla website, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A port change is transparent at Joomla level. You can change it without affecting your Joomla site

Comment: ok will change the port and will post the answer....

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have Joomla installed on XAMPP server in your local machine which is using port 80. Changing that port would not affect Joomla! website. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12). Also you can easily change Skype to use different port if that is your problem.

Comment: on local machine the port change won't affect anything, but i want to know on server side will it affect the existing website..?

Comment: Since your server is working normally, your site will be OK also.